# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver in D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\CDbConnection.php:382 in yii1

Tags: php, mysql, yii, xampp, migration

I am working on a project using yii1.1 with MySQL database,
Db is connected and working fine, but when I run the **Migration** command in **protected folder** through **CMD** it gives the error as mentioned in the headline,
I have tried but on my system, it doesn't work but on the other machine, with the same settings, it works fine, Whereas the code is the same on both systems.
I have tried every possible solution available on StackOverflow but it didn't work.
The Error stack is below:

> CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could
> not find driver in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\CDbConnection.php:382 Stack
> trace:
> #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
> #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive(true)
> #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\base\CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
> #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\base\CModule.php(118): CModule->getComponent('applicationdb')
> #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\protected\models\AltSettings.php(33): CModule->__isset('applicationdb')
> #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1428): AltSettings->getDbConnection()
> #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1518): CActiveRecord->getTableAlias(true)
> #7 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\protected\models\AltSettings.php(131): CActiveRecord->findByAttributes(Array)
> #8 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\protected\models\AltSettings.php(159): AltSettings::getSettingValue('instance_status')
> #9 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\protected\commands\DbMigrationCommand.php(23):
> AltSettings->getApplicationDbName()
> #10 [internal function]: DbMigrationCommand->actionMigrate(1)
> #11 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\console\CConsoleCommand.php(172):
> ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(DbMigrationCommand), Array)
> #12 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\console\CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71):
> CConsoleCommand->run(Array)
> #13 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\console\CConsoleApplication.php(92):
> CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
> #14 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
> #15 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\framework\yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
> #16 D:\xampp\htdocs\ilmversity\protected\yiic.php(7): require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs...')
> #17 {main}

Console.php file is as follow

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db_name',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'db2name'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db_name',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

I have also mentioned the following code in the **main.php** config folder,

```
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=testdrive',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

I have also seen drivers in the config file
extension=mysqli (and extension=pdo-mysql) are not preceded by semi colons.

Comment: What is the "other system"? A server while your system is a local machine? In which way are they different from each other (OS, mysql version, php version, etc.)?

Comment: other system meant other PC, with the same windows, the same version, everything same is running on

Comment: If I read the error message correctly, the mysql driver is missing. Could you check if `extension=mysqli` (and `extension=pdo-mysql`) are not preceded by a semicolon?

Comment: Yes, both are not preceded by a semi colon,

Comment: You've got me stumped.

Comment: lol, Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hard to say with the amount of information we have from the question.